# How can i use seed method for create initial data for my context?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to use seed method like this;

```
        context.Reeves.AddOrUpdate(
            p => new { p.FirstName, p.LastName },
            new Reeve { FirstName = "A", LastName = "A" },
            new Reeve { FirstName = "B", LastName = "B" });
        context.SaveChanges();
        context.Districts.AddOrUpdate(
            p => p.Name,
            new District() { Name = "X", ReeveId = context.Reeves.First(r => r.FirstName == "A" && r.LastName == "A").Id },
            new District() { Name = "Y", ReeveId = context.Reeves.First(r => r.FirstName == "B" && r.LastName == "B").Id });
        context.SaveChanges();
```

I'm receiving error message that "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.District_dbo.Reeve_Id". The conflict occurred in database "ProjectTracking", table "dbo.Reeve", column 'Id'."

If i change the code like below;

```
        context.Districts.AddOrUpdate(
            p => p.Name,
            new District() { Name = "X", Reeve = context.Reeves.First(r => r.FirstName == "A" && r.LastName == "A") },
            new District() { Name = "Y", Reeve = context.Reeves.First(r => r.FirstName == "B" && r.LastName == "B") });
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Error message disapear but when i check the districts table i see all ReeveId columns are 0.

**What is my mistake, any idea?**

**PS**: I dont want to create inline Reeve's inside District's AddOrUpdate methods. Something like; context.Districts.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, new District() { Name = "X", Reeve = new Reeve () { FirstName = "A", LastName = "A" });

**My Entities**

```
public class Reeve
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName); }
    }
    public virtual District District { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}

public class District
{
    public District()
    {
        Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
        ProjectRequests = new HashSet<ProjectRequest>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ReeveId { get; set; }
    public virtual Reeve Reeve { get; set; }
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProjectRequest> ProjectRequests { get; set; }
}
```

**Entity Configurations**

```
public class ReeveConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Reeve>
    {
        public ReeveConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey<int>(p => p.Id);
            Ignore(p => p.FullName);
            Property(p => p.FirstName).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("FullName", 1) { IsUnique = true })).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.LastName).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("FullName", 2) { IsUnique = true })).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.RowVersion).IsRowVersion();
        }
    }

public class DistrictConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<District>
    {
        public DistrictConfiguration()
        {
            HasKey<int>(p => p.Id);
            HasRequired(p => p.Reeve).WithOptional(p => p.District);
            HasMany(p => p.Projects).WithRequired(p => p.District).HasForeignKey(p => p.DistrictId);
            HasMany(p => p.ProjectRequests).WithRequired(p => p.District).HasForeignKey(p => p.DistrictId);
            Property(p => p.Name).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute() { IsUnique = true })).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
            Property(p => p.RowVersion).IsRowVersion();
        }
    }
```

I hate entity framework team's 1 to 1 relationship rules. Delegated entity is must be same name PK with principle entity and also delegated entity PK must be also FK. This  must be a joke. All 1 to 1 relationship can not be like Person -> PersonPhoto or Car -> Steering wheel. Am i right or i misunderstand their logic. For example i have also project and project request entities, project's request and request's project can be null i mean they have 0..1 to 0..1 relationship and they must be own PK Id's. Also how about that if i have Entity base class that have Id primary key field. How can i derived my 1 to 1 relation entities from that.

Comment: What do your models look like? Your error mentions Reeve_Id then you say ReeveId columns are zero. If you have both a ReeveId and Reeve_Id in District, then your relationship is not right.

Comment: I updated my post with entities and their configurations. Also if my 1 to 1 relationship is wrong like your said then i want to share my other entities that are project and projectrequest which their relationship is 0..1 to 0..1.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved my problem myself. Let's talk again my expectations. I want to write base class for my entities, at first step it's only contain Id property. Also i want to control my foreign key names, i don't want to ef do it for me automatically.

Also let's talk about received error too. I can not seed data and receive an error because of ef creating foreign key for me automatically and in district entity ReeveId column creating something like other data column. So when i set District.ReeveId with existing reeve and save changes ef throw foreign key error.

I do below changes to my code for solve the problem toward ef and my expectations;

- Delete ReeveId from district entity because there is no need
- Add HasRequired(p => p.Reeve).WithOptional(p => p.District).Map(m => m.MapKey("ReeveId")); code to my district configuration

So both table contain own Id column for primary key, district also have ReeveId column for foreign key. As a result ef and my expectations met.